# Ошибка при компиляции

Tags: c, gcc

Имеется такой код на Си:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG  1

#if DEBUG == 1
    printf("Debug status is 1 \n");
#elif DEBUG == 2
    printf("Debug status is 2 \n"); 
#else
    #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("Debug is defined! \n");
    #endif
    #ifndef DEBUG
        printf("Debug is not defined! \n");
    #endif
#endif

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

При компиляции gcc выдает такую ошибку:

> error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before string constant
>     printf("Debug status is 1 \n");

С чем это связано?

Comment: А вы делаете вызов вне тела процедуры, поэтому это не считается вызовом - а считается обьявлением. Ну а если так обьявлять функцию - то правильно пишет ошибку.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если пропустить ваш код через препроцессор, то получится такой результат:

```
printf("Debug status is 1 \n");

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

Код находится вне функции, на что компилятор и ругается. Правильно будет так:

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define DEBUG  1

int main()
{
#if DEBUG == 1
    printf("Debug status is 1 \n");
#elif DEBUG == 2
    printf("Debug status is 2 \n"); 
#else
    #ifdef DEBUG
        printf("Debug is defined! \n");
    #endif
    #ifndef DEBUG
        printf("Debug is not defined! \n");
    #endif
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Заработало. Я просто учу Си по одной книге и в ней автор о такой проблеме не указал. У него все работало почему-то.

Comment: @Amareth можно эту книгу сюда?

Comment: @Amareth: В книге, я уверен, ничего подобного не было.

Comment: Если вместо `printf()` использовать `#warning`, то всё наверняка сработает ещё на этапе препроцессинга ;)

Comment: Ивзините что долго не отвечал. Книга МакГрат`а "Язык Си для начинающих". И правда, автор похоже подразумевал что я и так воткну все это в main(). Так-что я просто не правильно понял, признаю.